# Перенос текста из одного ListBox в другой

Tags: c++

Прошу, подскажите, мне нужно перенести весь текст элемента ListBox в другой. Этот код переносит почему-то только часть текста:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button2Click(TObject *Sender)
{
for (int i = 0; i < ListBox1->Items->Count; ++i)
{
   ListBox2->Items->Add(ListBox1->Items->Strings[i]);
   ListBox1->Items->Delete(i);
   }
}
```

Узнал

```
ListBox2->Items->Assign(ListBox1->Items)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно и так, как Вы задумывали, но без логических ошибок:

```
    while(ListBox1->Items->Count > 0)
   {
     ListBox2->Items->Add(ListBox1->Items->Strings[0]);
     ListBox1->Items->Delete(0); 
   }
```